# Python Error with QGis2Web on QGIS 3.6.3 Noosa

Tags: qgis, python, error, qgis2web

I'm receiving a Python Error when trying to create a web map using QGIS2Web and for the life of me cannot figure out what to do.

Running QGIS 3.6.3 Noosa
Windows 10 Professional

```
KeyError: 100 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rodney/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\qgis2web.py", line 60, in run
    self.dlg = MainDialog(self.iface)
  File "C:/Users/Rodney/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.autoUpdatePreview()
  File "C:/Users/Rodney/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 320, in autoUpdatePreview
    self.previewMap()
  File "C:/Users/Rodney/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 323, in previewMap
    preview_file = self.createPreview()
  File "C:/Users/Rodney/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 286, in createPreview
    dest_folder=utils.tempFolder()).index_file
  File "C:/Users/Rodney/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\olwriter.py", line 91, in write
    folder=dest_folder)
  File "C:/Users/Rodney/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\olwriter.py", line 130, in writeOL
    popup, json, restrictToExtent, extent, feedback, matchCRS)
  File "C:/Users/Rodney/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\utils.py", line 220, in exportLayers
    iface, extent, precision, crs, optimize)
  File "C:/Users/Rodney/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\utils.py", line 233, in exportVector
    cleanLayer = writeTmpLayer(layer, restrictToExtent, iface, extent)
  File "C:/Users/Rodney/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\utils.py", line 162, in writeTmpLayer
    uri = TYPE_MAP[layer.wkbType()]
KeyError: 100
```

Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.6.3-Noosa Noosa, 0c5774c068

Python Path:

```
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.6/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/Rodney/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/Rodney/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\bin\python37.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/Rodney/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\Rodney\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins
C:/Users/Rodney/Google Drive/QGis
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message says that the key `100` is not found in this line `uri = TYPE_MAP[layer.wkbType()]`. So `layer.wkbType()` returns `100` which is the code for `NoGeometry`. So I guess you have a layer with no geometry set. If you can somehow disable or remove that layer it might work. Alternative try to update QGIS2Web. Looking at the source code you can see that an if statement handling layers with NoGeometry have been added 25 days ago: [GitHub Blame (line 146)](https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/blame/master/qgis2web/utils.py#L146)

Comment: Thanks, it did end up being a couple of layers with no geometry.  Now i'm able to publish just fine.